# Poor gaming performance from laptop

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, performance, gpu, gaming

My laptop Acer E5 551G has been giving me poor graphical performance, the specs are as follows:-

- AMD APU Quad Core A10 Processor (5th Gen) with R6 Graphics
- R7 M265 2GB
- 8GB RAM

I recently installed the latest Crimson Relive drivers for my GPU, but I got poor performance in the beginning with Catalyst driver as well.

So after installing the drivers, I installed MSI Afterburner to check for any bottleneck, but to my surprise CPU was running at 60-70% and the GPU was also being utilized at only 40-50%. The GPU was at around 80-90 C and was at its maximum frequency of 820 MHz.

I am not able to understand what I should do to improve the performance of my laptop.

By poor performance I mean, CS:GO 30-35 FPS at 1366x768 resolution. I also tested other games like Dirty Bomb, FarCry3, Paladins and got a similar results with sub-optimal utilization of CPU and GPU resources.

Tried running at all settings from Low to Ultra, the GPU usage jumps up to 80% in Ultra and the fps remains more or less the same.

Comment: I think you need to lower your expectations - that's pretty good performance for such a low-end APU

Comment: I don't have very high expectations, it's just that the resources are not being used.

Comment: At 60-70% CPU usage and 40-50% GPU usage what are your expected numbers? The CPU is likely a multi core CPU and CS:GO probably still single threaded so your CPU might be the bottleneck.

Comment: Well even the individual core usages are in that range and I want to fully utilize my GPU and CPU.

Comment: Is it possible that somehow you have V-sync enabled? If not through game settings, perhaps from an AMD software? If that's the case, [that can explain the ~30fps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198184/what-is-v-sync-and-when-should-i-enable-it).

Comment: You won't see "full utilization" as some of your components are bottle necking your other components.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you could check is if it's actually using the R7 and not the APU. Chances are it would be a HD graphics card [on the APU](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/processors/desktop/a-series-apu).

But even otherwise you just don't have a powerful card. According to the [specifications](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/notebook/r7-m200), the card uses normal DDR3 memory and runs a 825 MHz tops.

If you look at [benchmark comparisons](https://www.futuremark.com/hardware/gpu/AMD+Radeon+R7+M265/review) it's really not that strong compared to current tech. As you didn't say anything about the settings you're running those games on it might actually just be adequate performance. As  it's a notebook there is little you can change about it as you can't change any of the components.

Comment: It is running on the r7 m265 confirmed using afterburner

Comment: I have tried all settings from low to high and the fps stays more or less the same, it is just that the GPU usage increases a bit.

Comment: You can't push a piece of string, you have to pull it. FPS will be affected by any bottleneck, CPU/GPU/RAM/HD etc etc etc. All must be capable of keeping up with the task.